# ExtJS resizable windows keeping aspect ratio

Tags: extjs, window, aspect-ratio, extjs6

I am trying to resize windows in ExtJS 6, and they resize fine, but I would like to resize them whilst maintaining the aspect ratio, but so far after an extensive google search and trying many options, I cannot seem to find a solution.

I have a simple window with two panels in with textfield in one and a button in the other to begin with whilst I figure this out - below is a sample of the code in which I am trying to apply this to.

```
Ext.define('SenchaApp.view.MainView', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

autoShow: true,
height: 600,
width: 600,
constrainHeader: true,
title: 'Main View',

items:[{
    xtype: 'panel',
    height: 200,
    width: 600,

        items:[{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            text: 'my button'
        }]
   },
   {
    xtype: 'panel',
    height: 200,
    width: 600,

        items:[{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'my button'
        }]
   }
]
});
```

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.resizer.Resizer-cfg-preserveRatio

Answer (score 0):

Use the `resizable` config in your window which can be a config object of `Ext.resizer.Resizer`. The `Resizer` class has a `preserveRatio` config for exactly what you want.

```
resizable: {
    preserveRatio: true
}
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11rh

Comment: But when I resize this, the button doesn't go in respect with the window as I had tried this already, as I resize, I would expect everything in the window to also 'resize' so it is still in the same positions even if the window size is different.

Comment: That requirement wasn't in your original post also I don't see why you'd expect that. You gave the child panels a size (200px height, 600px width) and they will always have that size, there is nothing there that would dynamically size the children. Instead, you should give the window the vbox layout with stretch align, remove the height & width from the child panels and give the child panels a flex of 1. Like this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11sr